# Windows 10 start menu management

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The Windows 10 Start Menu is doing some odd things. Autodesk programs will place shortcuts in a program specific folder in the Autodesk folder, for example
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\Revit 2018`

However, the Start menu basically ignores that last folder and lists all links under Autodesk in the start menu. Given that most Autodesk programs have anywhere from 3 to 5 or 6 links, and AEC first often have 4-5 Autodesk programs installed, and often multiple years as well, you can easily get 30-40 shortcuts under Autodesk, which is basically useless.

However, some programs are presented correctly it seems, so I assume there's some information somewhere that forces one behavior or the other. Any suggestions on a thread to follow?

Comment: Sounds like a case for a third-party solution to change the behavior of the Windows 10 start menu

Comment: It might be worth your time to make a new Windows user, and see if the Start menu behaves in a better way for you there.

Comment: When you say "some programs are presented correct" do you mean that some items in the start menu are enclosed in multiple nested subfolders? It's not super clear what you mean there. Basically, Windows 10 removes nested subfolders entirely, AFAIK. It is poor form anyways to have many dozens of entries in the start menu for a program (Autodesk isn't the only offender), MS just made that problem obvious.